# Congratulations Modal doesn't Pop Up

Tags: jquery

I am doing a matching game project, where when all the cards match the game over and congratulations pop up. But it doesn't work in my code. Could you please go through it and rectify my mistake. So it works properly.

Here is the snippet of my index.html code [the modal section]

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Congratulations!!!</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="myText"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-default" onclick="gameStart(), $rating.removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');">Play Again!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript section for this is

```
function gameOver(moves, score) {
    $('#myText').text(`Time: ${second} Seconds, Your Move: ${moves} Moves, Total Score: ${score}, Well done!!!`);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
}


// Game Over after all cards have been matched, with a short delay
if (cardList === match) {
    rating(moves);
    let score = rating(moves).score;
    setTimeout(function () {
        gameOver(moves, score);
    },800);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous answer pointed out, `$('#myModal').toggle();` to display the modal.

You are not seeing the modal because the final check which triggers `gameOver` function does a match with `cardList` which is always 16.

```
if (cardList === match) {
            rating(moves);
            let score = rating(moves).score;
            setTimeout(function () {
                gameOver(moves, score);
            },800);
        }
```

The check should be against `totalCard` which is 8 and the value of `match` also equates 8 after you've matched all the cards.

```
if (totalCard === match) {
  rating(moves);
  let score = rating(moves).score;
  setTimeout(function () {
    gameOver(moves, score);
  },800);
}
```

Also, since you are using bootstrap modals, you could use `modal('toggle')` as well to show/hide modal. For this to work, you've got to include `popper.js` CDN, in the below order. But the jquery one just works fine. Just an extra note for your knowledge.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at

```
$('#myModal').toggle();
```

Refer to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: thanks, but still, my congratulations modal does not pop up, after game over. I do not know why?

Comment: Because your if block appears to be called in the root location of your script. Please do execute it after the game is actually over